# void implementation error for Insert function of binary search tree (In C)

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, void-pointers

For an assignment, I was asked to write the insert function for a binary search tree, where the item points to a struct which holds a word and how many times it occurs. After searching for the standard implementation for an insert function for a BST I came up with this:

```
// Insert an item into the tree rooted at node n.
// If the tree already has a node for that item, do nothing.

void insert(BSTnode *n, void *item, int compare(void * a, void * b)){
  BSTnode *new_node = (BSTnode *)item;
  BSTnode *currentNode = n;
    if(n==NULL){
      BSTnode *new = createNode(item);
      return new;
    }

    else if(compare(((WordCount*)new_node->item)->word, ((WordCount*)currentNode->item)->word)==0){
      return;
    }

    else if(compare(((WordCount*)new_node->item)->word, ((WordCount*)currentNode->item)->word) > 0){
      n->right = insert(n->right, item, compare);
    }

    else{
      n->left = insert(n->left, item, compare);
    }
}
```

However I get a "void value not ignored as it ought to be" since I can't do

```
 n->right = insert(n->right, item, compare);
```

How could I modify this insert function? I am stuck and don't really know what to do since it is a void function.

Comment: @ovecssomuchjk Do not spend your time by modifying a bad code. Write your own good code.:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//start of insert
void insert(BSTnode *n, void *item, int compare(void * a, void * b))
{
    BSTnode *new_node = (BSTnode *)item;
    BSTnode *currentNode = n;
    if(n==NULL) // if root is null
    {
        BSTnode *node = createNode(item);
        n = node;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        insertSub(n, item, compare); // walk over the tree recursive with itemsub
    }
}

void insertSub(BSTnode *n, void *item, int compare(void * a, void * b))
{
    BSTnode *new_node = (BSTnode *)item;
    BSTnode *currentNode = n;
    if(compare(((WordCount*)new_node->item)->word, ((WordCount*)currentNode->item)->word) > 0)
    {
        if(n->right == NULL) //if right child = null then create the desired node
        {
            n->right = createNode(item);
            return; // go out of the tree
        }
        else
        {
            insertSub(n->right, item, compare); walk
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(n->left == NULL) //if left child = null then create desired node
        {
            n->left = createNode(item);
            return; // go out of the tree
        }
        else
        {
            insertSub(n->left, item, compare);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you :)